# XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Сделала автозаполнение с помощью простого скрипта.
Вот скрипт

```js
var MIN_LENGTH = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#keyword").keyup(function() {
  var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
  if (keyword.length >= MIN_LENGTH) {

   $.get( "auto-complete.php", { keyword: keyword } )
   .done(function( data ) {
    $('#results').html('');
    var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $(results).each(function(key, value) {
     $('#results').append('<div class="item">' + value + '</div>');
    })

       $('.item').click(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        $('#keyword').val(text);
       })

   });
  } else {
   $('#results').html('');
  }
 });

    $("#keyword").blur(function(){
      $("#results").fadeOut(500);
     })
        .focus(function() {  
         $("#results").show();
     });

});
```

Загрузила сайт на сервер agava. И вылетает в консоли "MLHttpRequest cannot load http://err.agava.ru/vh/500.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует использовать [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Говоря простым языком, CORS - система контроля безопасности. Сервер должен "разрешить" вашему скрипту загружать свои ресурсы. Для этого достаточно указать в заголовке ответа Access-Control-Allow-Origin список доверенных доменов.

Готовые примеры использования можно найти [здесь](http://enable-cors.org/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

В файл `auto-complete.php` добавь заголовок:

> header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');